# Call to undefined method onlyTrashed()

Tags: laravel, undefined

anyone can help me?

how to resolve ->

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\ModalName::onlyTrashed()
```

my controller ->

```
public function destroy(Abc $abc)
    {
        $abc= Abc::destroy($abc->id)->get();
        return redirect('/dir/abcdir')-> with('delete', 'aaa');
    }
```

Comment: do u use soft-delete in your model?

Comment: Please post the code of your Model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, you need to use traits 'SoftDeletes'.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Flight extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

PS:
Please post complete code of your controller and model.

Answer (score 2):

For SoftDelete to work in Laravel Eloquent Model

1. You must use `SoftDeletes` Trait
2. Table schema should have `$table->softDeletes();` which will add `deleted_at` column in the table.

Reference: [Eloquent Soft-Delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while the softDeletes was implemented, but the model had an overwritten contructor with a missing parent call. If somebody stumbles across the problem of the undefined method always worth a check.

```
class SaleOrder extends Model
{
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        // Custom logic
    }
}
```